# Return value from within a range in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, select

I have two tables, one where it contains members & their cardnumbers, and outlet table which identifies the cardnumber ranges per outlet. I want to know which store the cardnumber the member has belongs to.

Members Table

```
MemberID    Cardnumber    FirstName   LastName
1           123456123     John        Doe
2           123456245     Sarah       Smith
```

Outlets Table

```
OutletID    OutletName      StartCardNumber     EndCardNumber
1           Balmain Store   123456100           123456200
2           Sydney Store    123456201           123456300
```

I can't think of a script which I can bring back the following information without having to 
create a temp table first. Is there an easier way?

```
CardNumber  FirstName LastName   OutletName
123456123   John      Doe        Balmain Store
123456245   Sarah     Smith      Sydney Store
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple. You join on a range using inequalities in addition to equalities.

```
SELECT
   M.CardNumber,
   M.FirstName,
   M.LastName,
   O.OutletName
FROM
   dbo.Members M
   INNER JOIN dbo.Outlets O
      ON M.CardNumber >= O.StartCardNumber
      AND M.CardNumber <= O.EndCardNumber
```

This is the same as `M.CardNumber BETWEEN O.StartCardNumber AND O.EndCardNumber` but I wanted to draw out the inclusive endpoints of your scheme using `>=` and `<=`. `BETWEEN` is not always suitable because very often the end value is exclusive requiring `<`, but not in this case.

[Try this out right now online](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b1542/1)!